# how to data.frame convert to atomic vector in r

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have following data object. object name is seoul1

```
   V3    V4    V5      V6    V7    V8  V9
   531 789 894 1,447 1,202 1,186 501

typeof = list, class = data.frame
```

I want to convert these data to atomic vecter consisting of integer or double

I used 'for' code

```
 for(i  in 1:7){
 h[i]<-as.numeric(seoul1[2,][[i]])
  }
```

but result is as below

```
for(i in 1:7){

h[i]<-as.numeric(seoul1[2,][[i]])

}

Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: NAs introduced by coercion 
3: NAs introduced by coercion 

    print(h)

[1] 531 789 894  NA  NA  NA 501
```

why this error happen to, I don't know

Comment: The warnings are because of `as.numeric("1,447")` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `unlist` to create a `vector`, then convert to `numeric` after removing the `,`.

```
as.numeric(sub(",", "", unlist(seoul1[2,], use.names=FALSE)))
#[1]  531  789  894 1447 1202 1186  501
```

In the OP's example dataset, there are elements like `l,447, 1,202, 1,186` which will be 'character' elements and when we convert to 'numeric' with `as.numeric`, it will coerce to NA because of the `,`.  There is no `error` message.  It is a friendly `warning`   Remove the `,` with `sub` and then do the `as.numeric`.

NOTE: If there are multiple `,` within an element use `gsub` instead of `sub`